# Count up in the following shema

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
   var Ok = {
       defineVars : function ()
       {
           var integerr = 0;
           for(i=0; i<5; i++)
           {
               Ok.countUp(integerr);
           }
       },
       countUp : function (integerr)
       {
           integerr = integerr + 1;

           console.log(integerr);
       }
   }
   Ok.defineVars();
```

This is a very simplified of the real code. It would take me too long to explain what my behavior is, but i need to add an variable to integerr definied as 0 in Ok.defineVars();

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately integerr is not passed by reference, so it's always 0. You can either change the structure to make integerr a 'global' variable accessible by both functions:

```
 var Ok = {
       integerr: 0,
       defineVars : function ()
       {
           for(i=0; i<5; i++)
           {
               Ok.countUp(Ok.integerr);
           }
       },
       countUp : function (integerr)
       {
           Ok.integerr = integerr + 1;

           console.log(Ok.integerr);
       }
   }
   Ok.defineVars();
```

Or take advantage of objects that are passed by reference and do something like:

```
var Ok = {
       defineVars : function ()
       {
           var integerr = {num:0};
           for(i=0; i<5; i++)
           {
               Ok.countUp(integerr);
           }
       },
       countUp : function (integerr)
       {
           integerr.num = integerr.num + 1;

           console.log(integerr.num);
       }
   }
   Ok.defineVars();
```

Comment: thank you! The second way works perfectly :)